# EditFor only Year in Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a little quiz editing only "Year" part in Date field.
I've tried a naive approach with formatting attributes:

```
Partial Public Class Book
    Public Property BookID As Integer
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Author As String
    <DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode:=True, DataFormatString:="{0:yyyy}")>
    Public Property Year As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property CategoryID As Integer
    Public Property Image As Byte()

    Public Overridable Property Category As Category

End Class
```

My View is

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Year)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Year)%>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work. When I write "2014" in input field and press "Submit" validation checker tells me that "2014" is not valid date.
So how can I solve this task?

Comment: Why store the year as a date and not an integer?

Comment: If all you want is the year then just make the field an `int` rather than a `DateTime`, the compiler can't make a date out of a year it has to know the day & month...

Comment: You've defined Year as a Date type but are only submitting an integer value for the year part, do you need to define Year as an int then validate the input value, or write a custom model binder that accepts an int but outputs a date?

Comment: @StuTheDog I think second approach is better.
P.S. (to everyone) Storing integer rather than date is just unacceptable :)

Comment: Why is it unacceptable?

Comment: @DavidG Entity model was generated from database where "Year" field has Date type. I'm not authorized to change this.

Comment: Not authorised doesn't mean they can't be changed.